# Why didn't crontab didn't run automatically to backup database with Barman?

Tags: linux, backup, cron

Operate user: barman

If run these 2 commands, it can work:

```
/usr/bin/barman cron
/usr/bin/barman backup pg
```

Set them to crontab:

```
crontab -e
* * * * * /usr/bin/barman cron
0 4 * * * /usr/bin/barman backup pg
```

Crontab service status:

```
systemctl status crond
● crond.service - Command Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-02-21 10:40:58 JST; 2 weeks 0 days ago
 Main PID: 23099 (crond)
   CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
           └─23099 /usr/sbin/crond -n
```

Localtime:

```
ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Mar 26  2019 /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo
```

But it didn't run backup at 4 o'clock today. Why?

---

## Add Test

Tested:

```
40 18 * * * /usr/bin/barman cron
41 18 * * * /usr/bin/barman backup pg
```

See log:

```
less /var/log/cron
...
Mar  6 18:40:02 server crond[23099]: (barman) RELOAD (/var/spool/cron/barman)
Mar  6 18:40:02 server CROND[13013]: (barman) CMD (/usr/bin/barman cron)
Mar  6 18:40:02 server CROND[13014]: (barman) CMD (  [ -x /usr/bin/barman ] && /usr/bin/barman -q cron)
Mar  6 18:40:02 server CROND[13015]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Mar  6 18:41:01 server CROND[13117]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Mar  6 18:41:01 server CROND[13119]: (barman) CMD (  [ -x /usr/bin/barman ] && /usr/bin/barman -q cron)
Mar  6 18:41:01 server CROND[13118]: (barman) CMD (/usr/bin/barman backup pg)
```

It seems the task started, but didn't backup database. If run `/usr/bin/barman backup pg` can do.

Comment: Are there any environment variables in your shell that `/usr/bin/barman backup pg` relies on?

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a new line after the last command. If you look at `/var/log/cron` or wherever your cron logs are kept, you'll see an error indicating this.

To get the job to run, go into `crontab -e` and press `ENTER` at the end of the last line so that the cursor is on the next line and then save it. The last job will then run.

Comment: Thank you. I used your way to do a realtime test, added the result to the question. Could you have a look at it?